# Difference boolean[] b = {false} vs. boolean b = false?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

What is the difference between:

```
boolean[] cameraPermissionGranted = {false};
```

and

```
boolean cameraPermissionGranted = false;
```

??

There is nor problem, both work. 
I just want to know what is the difference on the memory for instance. 
What is the difference regarding prerformance issues..

Comment: array of element Vs single element.

Comment: The first one is an array of `boolean`s. An array is a *collection* of elements (not necessarily only one). The second is just **one** `boolean`.

Comment: It is like comparing banana with box. This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) since aspect which interests you lies probably in part of code which you are not showing us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference between these primarily is that

```
boolean[] cameraPermissionGranted = {false};
```

is an array that persists `boolean` type of data initialized with single element `false` at present unless resized(re-initialized) while

```
boolean cameraPermissionGranted = false;
```

is just an attribute that is initialized as `false` and can be updated thereafter.

---

One of the very intuitive example that comes to my mind for that is usage in lambda's :

```
boolean[] cameraPermissionGranted = {false};
boolean cameraPermission = false;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.forEach(a -> {
    cameraPermissionGranted[0] = true; // effectively final
    // cannot use cameraPermission
});
```

Comment: Well, it's not *very* intuitive. AtomicBoolean would be better.

Answer (score 4):

`boolean[] cameraPermissionGranted = {false};` create a boolean array, it's first element is `false`.

`boolean cameraPermissionGranted = false;` create a boolean variable, it's value is `false`.

Comment: yes thats clear, but why would someone use first varient? Any performance issues? Any other advantages?

Comment: The array is an object, instead of a primitive variable, so it can be stored in a Map? (but in that case using a Boolean object is a better solution)

Answer (score 3):

The first one creates a single element boolean array, the other creates a boolean type.

The former is often used in places where final is required and element modification is desirable, such as closures, although modern Java versions introduce other more readable and less subversive techniques. It is also somewhat analogous to the reference type of C++: you can pass the array reference to a function and that function can modify the array element and such modifications will be seen by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

One reason of the use of the first one would be to mimic a C++ *pass-by-reference*. Consider the following example in C++:

```
void toggleValue(bool &b){
    b = !b;
}
```

It seems hard to do it in Java since you cannot pass a parameter by reference. But with a singleton array, you can mimic the same behavior :

```
private void toggleValue(boolean[] b){
    b[0] = !b[0];
}
```